# How to implement merkle tree data in a relational database table to validate the records in the database table

Tags: java, postgresql, database-design, audit-tables

I have a REST service which insert the audit record into the database say MySQL. I have to implement merkle tree in such a way that whenever the service insert the record in database it should verify the the table records and insert the data. Or, if we get the id of the record we can check that whether the record is valid or not.

I had used this merkle tree implementation

https://github.com/SimoneStefani/merkle-tree-java/blob/master/src/test/java/NodeTest.java

Requirement is how to design a database which store merkle tree. With each and every insertion we need to add a leaf and the whole tree will change. How to maintain the database record. I want to implement **Single Table authentication** or **Level Based Authentication Table**.

Comment: Have you look at the daml.com, there are there is not any plugin for MySQL but there is one for Postgres and Aws Aurora